# Cloud firestore orderby not working on flutter ( error log involved )

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

this is my code

```
  late final Stream<QuerySnapshot> products = productsRef
  .where('submitters', arrayContains: uid)
  .where('postState', isNotEqualTo: 'completed')
  .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
  .snapshots();
```

here's the error log
[image]

without orderBy it works fine

Comment: Looks like it means what it says.  Your orderBy has to refer to a field selected by a where clause.  It isn't.

Comment: In the future please don't paste images of textual content, as it makes it hard to search for it. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: you're right, I'll do it next time 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compound queries must `orderBy` on the same field as you are filtering by. In this case it would be `postState` for you. You are limited to order by that field since you are using it for `!=` comparison.

It is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation, it is hinted in this note on limitations: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations

Since you are not using a `limit()` on your query, you can still accomplish the same result by piping your result set and implement an array-sort locally on the `createdAt` field.

Comment: no worry , I'll do it if there is no more good answer, 
now I'm just waiting another answers. don't wait for me though can't promise when